# Specifying an Index (Non-Unique Key) Using JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, jpa, datanucleus

How do you define a field, eg `email` as having an index using JPA annotations. We need a non-unique key on `email` because there are literally millions of queries on this field per day, and its a bit slow without the key.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="person", 
       uniqueConstraints=@UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"code", "uid"}))
public class Person {
    // Unique on code and uid
    public String code;
    public String uid;

    public String username;
    public String name;
    public String email;
}
```

I have seen a hibernate specific annotation but I am trying to avoid vendor specific solutions as we are still deciding between hibernate and datanucleus.

UPDATE:

As of JPA 2.1, you can do this. See: [The annotation @Index is disallowed for this location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17620405/the-annotation-index-is-disallowed-for-this-location)

Comment: I would be great if you could update the answer so people find that with JPA 2.1 there is really a way to do it

Comment: Why don't you accept the most upvoted answer?

Answer (score 240, accepted):

With JPA 2.1 you should be able to do it.

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Index;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "region",
       indexes = {@Index(name = "my_index_name",  columnList="iso_code", unique = true),
                  @Index(name = "my_index_name2", columnList="name",     unique = false)})
public class Region{

    @Column(name = "iso_code", nullable = false)
    private String isoCode;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

}
```

**Update**: If you ever need to create and index with two or more columns you may use commas. For example:

```
@Entity
@Table(name    = "company__activity", 
       indexes = {@Index(name = "i_company_activity", columnList = "activity_id,company_id")})
public class CompanyActivity{
```

Comment: Thanks to Alvin for his answer. (+1 vote). But I had to look for a few things a I hope this example may make your life easier

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for - a simple and clean code snipped - not only describing the whole thing. Thanks +1.

Comment: @borjab - can you please give me a hint where I can find an "official" example or specification for using the `@Index`annotation within the `@Table` annotation? I've searched on [JSR 338](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr338/index.html) but I didn't find it there. Your post is very useful to me.

Comment: @Ulrich Not exactly the official documentatio but oracle blog https://blogs.oracle.com/arungupta/entry/jpa_2_1_schema_generation

Comment: I wonder, if I have a column with @Column(unique = true), does it get merged to the indexes list (since unique is also an index)?

Comment: what the benefit of @index ,is it use binary search ?

Comment: @IshanGarg: If you generate the database structure from JPA this allows you to generate the index in the database

Answer (score 41):

## A unique hand-picked collection of Index annotations

#### = Specifications =

- [JPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Persistence_API) 2.1+: [`javax.persistence.Index`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Index.html) (or see [JSR-000338](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/persistence-2_2-mrel-spec/JavaPersistence.pdf) PDF, p. 452, item 11.1.23)
  The JPA `@Index` annotation can only be used as part of another annotation like `@Table`, `@SecondaryTable`, etc.:

  ```
  @Table(indexes = { @Index(...) })
  ```
- [JDO](https://db.apache.org/jdo/index.html) 2.1+: [`javax.jdo.annotations.Index`](https://db.apache.org/jdo/api31/jdo-api-3.1-javadoc/javax/jdo/annotations/Index.html)

#### = [ORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) Frameworks =

- ♥ [Hibernate ORM](http://hibernate.org/orm/): [`org.hibernate.annotations.Index`](https://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/app-server/HibernateAnnotations/reference/en/html_single/#d0e2041);
- [OpenJPA](https://openjpa.apache.org): `org.apache.openjpa.persistence.jdbc.Index` and `org.apache.openjpa.persistence.jdbc.ElementIndex` (see [Reference Guide](https://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.2.3/apache-openjpa/docs/ref_guide_mapping_jpa.html#ref_guide_mapping_jpa_index));
- [EclipseLink](https://eclipse.org/eclipselink/): [`org.eclipse.persistence.annotations.Index`](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/api/2.2/org/eclipse/persistence/annotations/Index.html);
- [DataNucleus](http://datanucleus.org): [`org.datanucleus.api.jpa.annotations.Index`](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/datanucleus/jpa/annotations.html#Index_Field);
- Carbonado [(GitHub)](https://github.com/Carbonado/Carbonado): [`com.amazon.carbonado.Index`](https://carbonado.github.io/Carbonado/apidocs/com/amazon/carbonado/Index.html);
- [EBean](https://ebean-orm.github.io/): com.avaje.ebean.annotation.Index or io.ebean.annotation.Index ?
- [Ujorm](http://ujorm.org/): Annotation [`org.ujorm.orm.annot.Column`](http://ujorm.org/javadoc/org/ujorm/orm/annot/Column.html#index()), `index` and `uniqueIndex` properties;
- requery ([GitHub](https://github.com/requery/requery). Java, Kotlin, Android): Annotation [`io.requery.Index`](https://github.com/requery/requery/blob/master/requery/src/main/java/io/requery/Index.java);
- [Exposed](https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed) ([Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/) SQL Library): [org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.Index](https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/org/jetbrains/exposed/sql/Constraints.kt#L59), [org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.Table#index()](https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/org/jetbrains/exposed/sql/Table.kt#L282). Example:

  ```
  object Persons : IdTable() {
      val code = varchar("code", 50).index()
  }
  ```

#### = ORM for [Android](https://www.android.com/) =

- ♥ [ActiveAndroid](http://www.activeandroid.com/): Annotation `com.activeandroid.annotation.Column` has [`index`](https://github.com/pardom/ActiveAndroid/wiki/Creating-your-database-model#setting-indexes), `indexGroups`, `unique`, and `uniqueGroups` properties;
  <sup>UPDATE [2018]: ActiveAndroid was a nice ORM 4 years ago, but unfortunately, the author of the library stopped maintaining it, so someone forked, fixed bugs, and rebranded it as [ReActiveAndroid](https://github.com/ImangazalievM/ReActiveAndroid) - use this if you're starting a new project or refer to [Migration Guide](https://imangazalievm.gitbooks.io/reactiveandroid/migration-from-activeandroid.html) if you want to replace ActiveAndroid in a legacy project.</sup>
- [ReActiveAndroid](https://imangazalievm.gitbooks.io/reactiveandroid/): Annotation `com.reactiveandroid.annotation.Column` has [`index`](https://github.com/ImangazalievM/ReActiveAndroid/blob/master/reactiveandroid/src/main/java/com/reactiveandroid/annotation/Index.java), `indexGroups`, `unique`, and `uniqueGroups` properties;
- [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/):  Annotation [`com.j256.ormlite.field.DatabaseField`](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/field/DatabaseField.html#index--) has an `index` property;
- [greenDAO](http://greenrobot.org/greendao/): [`org.greenrobot.greendao.annotation.Index`](http://greenrobot.org/files/greendao-api/javadoc/3.1/org/greenrobot/greendao/annotation/Index.html);
- ORMAN [(GitHub)](https://github.com/ahmetalpbalkan/orman): [`org.orman.mapper.annotation.Index`](https://github.com/ahmetalpbalkan/orman/blob/master/src/org/orman/mapper/annotation/Index.java);
- ★ DBFlow [(GitHub)](https://github.com/Raizlabs/DBFlow): [`com.raizlabs.android.dbflow.sql.index.Index`](https://github.com/Raizlabs/DBFlow/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/raizlabs/android/dbflow/sql/index/Index.java) ([example](https://github.com/Raizlabs/DBFlow/blob/master/usage/TriggersIndexesAndMore.md#indexes) of usage);
- [other](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/69) (lots of ORM libraries at the Android Arsenal).

#### = Other (difficult to categorize) =

- [Realm](https://realm.io/) - Alternative DB for iOS / Android: Annotation [`io.realm.annotations.Index`](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/annotations/Index.html);
- [Empire-db](https://empire-db.apache.org/) - a lightweight yet powerful relational DB abstraction layer based on JDBC. It has no schema definition through annotations;
- Kotlin NoSQL [(GitHub)](https://github.com/cheptsov/kotlin-nosql) - a reactive and type-safe DSL for working with NoSQL databases (PoC): ???
- [Slick](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.0.0/index.html) - Reactive Functional Relational Mapping for Scala. It has no schema definition through annotations.

Just go for one of them.

Answer (score 32):

JPA 2.1 (finally) adds support for indexes and foreign keys! See [this blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/arungupta/entry/jpa_2_1_schema_generation) for details. JPA 2.1 is a part of Java EE 7, which is out .

If you like living on the edge, you can get the latest snapshot for eclipselink from their [maven repository](http://download.eclipse.org/rt/eclipselink/maven.repo/) (groupId:org.eclipse.persistence, artifactId:eclipselink, version:2.5.0-SNAPSHOT). For just the JPA annotations (which should work with any provider once they support 2.1) use artifactID:javax.persistence, version:2.1.0-SNAPSHOT.

I'm using it for a project which won't be finished until after its release, and I haven't noticed any horrible problems (although I'm not doing anything too complex with it).

UPDATE (26 Sep 2013): Nowadays release and release candidate versions of eclipselink are available in the central (main) repository, so you no longer have to add the eclipselink repository in Maven projects. The latest release version is 2.5.0 but 2.5.1-RC3 is also present. I'd switch over to 2.5.1 ASAP because of issues with the 2.5.0 release (the modelgen stuff doesn't work).

Answer (score 10):

In JPA 2.1 you need to do the following

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Index;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity(name="TEST_PERSON")
@Table(
    name="TEST_PERSON", 
    indexes = {
       @Index(name = "PERSON_INDX_0", columnList = "age"),
       @Index(name = "PERSON_INDX_1", columnList = "fName"),
       @Index(name = "PERSON_INDX_1", columnList = "sName")  })
public class TestPerson {

    @Column(name = "age", nullable = false)
    private int age;

    @Column(name = "fName", nullable = false)
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "sName", nullable = false)
    private String secondName;

    @Id
    private long id;

    public TestPerson() {
    }
}
```

In the above example the table TEST_PERSON will have 3 indexes:

- unique index on the primary key ID
- index on AGE
- compound index on FNAME, SNAME

Note 1: You get the compound index by having two @Index annotations with the same name

Note 2: You specify the column name in the columnList not the fieldName

Comment: but the benefit of compound index ? is uses binary search while searching or impose unique constraint

Answer (score 5):

I'd really like to be able to specify database indexes in a standardized way but, sadly, this is not part of the JPA specification (maybe because DDL generation support is not required by the JPA specification, which is a kind of road block for such a feature).

So you'll have to rely on a provider specific extension for that. Hibernate, OpenJPA and EclipseLink clearly do offer such an extension. I can't confirm for DataNucleus but since indexes definition is part of JDO, I guess it does.

I really hope index support will get standardized in next versions of the specification and thus somehow disagree with other answers, I don't see any good reason to not include such a thing in JPA (especially since the database is not always under your control) for optimal DDL generation support.

By the way, I suggest downloading the JPA 2.0 spec.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, there isn't a cross-JPA-Provider way to specify indexes. However, you can always create them by hand directly in the database, most databases will pick them up automatically during query planning.

Comment: lol, thats assuming you have DBA's that do the job of a DBA (:

Comment: I find it slightly odd that there is a way to do "unique" but not a way to do an index.

Comment: @Jacob - Well it is important to know at the application level whether some field will be unique or not. Indexes, on the other hand, are for the purposes of optimizing the db access. There is no need (as far as I see) to know whether a column is an index or not at the java layer. Like you said, the DBA can set up an index if it seems that a particular column would benefit from it.

Comment: @Jacob, there's no Index suport because that is simply an optimization (usually an important one, but still an optimization). OTOH if a field (or set of fields) is unique or not depends on the model, and will affect correctness. Also, no need for a fully-fledged 200USD/Hr DBA, some simple index creation statements usually suffice.

Comment: JPA 2.1 Specifies [`javax.persistence.Index`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Index.html)

Answer (score 2):

EclipseLink provided an annotation (e.g. [@Index](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/api/2.2/org/eclipse/persistence/annotations/Index.html)) to define an index on columns.  There is an [example](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Indexes) of its use.  Part of the example is included...

The firstName and lastName fields are indexed, together and individually.

```
@Entity
@Index(name="EMP_NAME_INDEX", columnNames={"F_NAME","L_NAME"})  // Columns indexed together
public class Employee{
    @Id
    private long id;

    @Index                      // F_NAME column indexed
    @Column(name="F_NAME")
    private String firstName;

    @Index                      // L_NAME column indexed
    @Column(name="L_NAME")
    private String lastName;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

OpenJPA allows you to specify non-standard annotation to define index on property.

Details are [here](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/latest/docs/manual/manual.html#ref_guide_mapping_jpa_index).

Answer (score 1):

To sum up the other answers:

- Hibernate: [`org.hibernate.annotations.Index`](http://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/app-server/HibernateAnnotations/reference/en/html_single/#d0e2041)
- OpenJPA: [`org.apache.openjpa.persistence.jdbc.Index`](http://ci.apache.org/projects/openjpa/trunk/docbook/manual/ref_guide_mapping_jpa.html#ref_guide_mapping_jpa_constraints)
- EclipseLink: [`org.eclipse.persistence.annotations.Index`](http://eclipse.org/eclipselink/api/2.2/org/eclipse/persistence/annotations/Index.html)

I would just go for one of them. It will come with JPA 2.1 anyway and should not be too hard to change in the case that you really want to switch your JPA provider.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to do that using JPA annotation. And this make sense: where a UniqueConstraint clearly define a business rules, an index is just a way to make search faster. So this should really be done by a DBA.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is for EclipseLink 2.5, and it works (tested):

```
@Table(indexes = {@Index(columnList="mycol1"), @Index(columnList="mycol2")})
@Entity
public class myclass implements Serializable{
      private String mycol1;
      private String mycol2;
}
```

This assumes ascendant order.