# Hibernate set index on multiple columns while one of the columns is the ID

Tags: java, database, performance, hibernate, jpa

Is it possible to set index of multiple columns while the one of columns is the Primary Key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this post (googled **java hibernate jpa index**):

[JPA: defining an index column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6453231/jpa-defining-an-index-column)

[Specifying an Index (Non-Unique Key) Using JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3405229/specifying-an-index-non-unique-key-using-jpa)

http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/entity/index

Then see that (googled **java hibernate jpa index composite**):

[How to define index by several columns in hibernate entity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182950/how-to-define-index-by-several-columns-in-hibernate-entity)

Comment: I know that primary key is already index. my question is if I can put a new index which include two or more columns while one of them is the primary key ?

Comment: @johnSmith: I'm not sure whether you read them through. Last link shows how to define multiple column indexes. It doesn't care whether one of them is primary key or not. You can use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

`<id name="id" type="NumericInteger">
    <column  name="ID" index="INDEX01"/>
</id>`

```
The key is to remove column="ID"  as property of Node <id> and place it as <column> definition instead
```