# The annotation @Index is disallowed for this location

Tags: java, jpa, hibernate-annotations

When trying to use the `@Index` annotation from `javax.persistence`, Eclipse gives me this error.

I'm using it right before a `java.util.Date` field, inside a class annotated with `@Entity`.

Before, I was using `org.hibernate.annotations.Index` in the exact same place and it was fine.

The problem started after I've upgraded *hibernate-core* from *4.1.9.Final* to *4.3.0.Beta3* and *hibernate-commons-annotation*s from *4.0.1* to *4.0.2*. It says `@Index` is deprecated and recommends the `javax.persistence` one.

All docs and examples I've found put `@Index` before class members. What am I missing?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The JPA Index annotation can only be used as part of another annotation like `@Table`, `@SecondaryTable`, etc. (see the See Also section in the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Index.html)):

```
@Table(indexes = { @Index(...) })
```

Answer (score 2):

See here: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#annotations-jpa-index

use this:

```
@Table 
.......,indexes = @Index(columnList = ("COLUMN_NAME"),name="CUSTOM NAME AT INDEX",unique=false)
......
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `Eclipselink` you can add this import to your class:

```
import org.eclipse.persistence.annotations.Index;
```

Then add your `@Index` to your field like this:

```
public class FooClass {
   @Index
   int field1;
}
```

or

```
@Index(columnNames = {"field1", "field2"})
public class FooClass {       
   int field1;
   int field2;
}
```

Comment: I think the question is about JPA 2.1 @Index annotation, not a proprietary one.