# How does the @Index annotation work in JPA 2.1?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'am trying to test JPA's @Index annotation which is avaliable since 2.1. But I can't find the documention how to use it.

When I'am trying:

```
@Index(columnList = "firstName")
private String firstName;
```

.. then Eclipse says: "The annotation @Index is disallowed for this location"

Does anyone know how to use it? Or has found the documentation for it? :-)

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I've used the hibernate `@Index` annotation just as you have with no issues, but it appears that the JPA `@Index` annotation is stricter on where it can be used.  Taken from a previous question - [The annotation @Index is disallowed for this location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17620405/the-annotation-index-is-disallowed-for-this-location) :

> The JPA Index annotation can only be used as part of another annotation like `@Table`, `@SecondaryTable`, etc.

```
@Table(indexes = { @Index(...) })
```