# Equivalent of hibernate @Index?

Tags: java, hibernate

The hibernate annotation `@Index` is deprecated, but I can't find docs or any hints how to exchange it.

```
@Entity
class MyEntity {
      @Index(name = "name") //org.hibernate.annotations.Index
      private String name;

      @Index(name = "age")
      private int age;
}
```

Result:
`@deprecated Using {@link javax.persistence.Index} instead.`
But if I change the import: `Annotation disallowed for this location`.

So: how does the above entity have to look like when using non-deprecated index?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As specified by the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17620405/the-annotation-index-is-disallowed-for-this-location) the index annotation in `javax.persistence.Index` can only be used as part of another annotation.

```
@Table(name = "myTable", indexes = { @Index("name")})
@Entity
class MyEntity {
      @Index(name = "name")
      private String name;

      @Index(name = "age")
      private int age;
}
```

Comment: Should I only add the "name" index withint the `@Table` annotation? Or should I list all annotated indexes there?

Comment: If you just want "name" then just use name, it depends how many indexes you want on your table.  Don't forget you can have index combinations.

Comment: Could you correct your code example or make it more clear? If I understood correctly, the properties should not have any `@Index` annotations? Or is the annotation needed both in `@Table` and the property? Ist it possible to give indices a name? Hibernate's `@Index` supports this.

Comment: A more complete code exmple can be found in borjab's answer to the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3405229/1492329